# onreadystatechange not fired?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm fairly new to the javascript, I'm trying to create a chrome extension that works with my school's website, but I'm stuck here,
here is manifest.json

```
{
"name": "APPNAME",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Desc",
"icons": {
  "16": "assets/icon_16.png",
  "128": "assets/icon_128.png"
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://public.my.wisc.edu/*"],
    "js": ["main.js"]
  }
 ]
}
```

and here's the simple script that I'm trying to run,

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    alert("HELLO");
   }
};
```

This doesn't seem to work for the url above.
Is there a way to track document onreadystatechange attribute?

Comment: The state is `complete` when a content script is injected - by default it's [`"run_at": "document_idle"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at) so the ready state change event isn't triggered.

Comment: Okay, well I've been looking at this in debugger, when this script runs, it skips the entire line... what could be the issue?

Comment: The line is an assignment for the event listener. You don't need it. Just type your code without complicating stuff. What's the ultimate goal, anyway? Why do you need a ready state listener?

Comment: Well I guess I don't, the ultimate goal is to inject some HTMLs into the current website, so I want to run it when everything is completely loaded

Comment: Third time's a charm: no, you don't need it.

Comment: What I if need to run it after all DOM is loaded?

Comment: Er, as I said, the page has been loaded already when your content scripts runs.

Comment: I see, I see thank you so much